# Unable to test scope outside of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

In my protractor code I'm making a call to a page that has this particular bit of code:

```
var elem = angular.element(document.body);
var scope = elem.scope();
scope.$watch('errors',function(errors){
    if(errors.length > 0) {
        //Error Handling Code here
    }
}, false);
```

On a normal browser the following is spit out when I console.log scope:

`t {$$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: Array[5], $$listeners: Object…}`

With protractor accessing the page however, it's saying:

> undefined

Is there a particular way around this issue so that the test can properly replicate what the real browser is doing?

Edit:
Clarifying a few points to see if I can point to more of where the issue is

1) The errors are being properly set in the controller itself

2) The page is unable to access the scope outside of the controller when it's loaded in via Protractor

3) I'm trying to test that when the errors bubble up to the watch, that it shows the div with the error. It's not done via a directive as this app is a plugin for forms that have different ways of showing the errors

UPDATE2: Found a way around it by making a directive where I can specify an error callback function and setting up the watch in there

Comment: What are you trying to test? If you care about scope variables sounds more like a unit test scenario than a UI test?

Comment: I'm trying to test that when the page sees the errors update, that it shows the appropriate div that is displaying the error.